# How to create files with folder names recursively using script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I have a folder structure that can have x subfolders, like so:

- Folder 1

  - Sub-folder 1
  - Sub-folder 2

    - Sub-sub-folder 3
- Folder 2

I want to create an empty file that has the name of the sub-folders (with .file appended) in their parent folders, as presented here:

- Folder 1

  - Sub-folder 1.file (newly created file that has the same name as the sister folder)
  - Sub-folder 1
  - Sub-folder 2.file (newly created file that has the same name as the sister folder)
  - Sub-folder 2

    - Sub-sub-folder 3.file (newly created file that has the same name as the sister folder)
    - Sub-sub-folder 3
- Folder 2

Some folders might have spaces in their names, so I've tried the following but it's not working even though echoing $(dirname $dir)/$dir seems to yield the expected result:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -mindepth 1 -type d | while read dir
do
    touch $(dirname $dir)/$dir.file
done
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?
Thank you so much in advance!

post updated to try to be clearer

Comment: it is unclear to me: do you want a file and a folder with same name in same parent folder?

Comment: Is it even possible to have two files with the same name in the same directory?

Comment: try with touch $(dirname "$dir")/$(basename "$dir").file this should create a file with same name as directory but with extension .file

Comment: On the file systems I know you cannot have a directory and a file with the same name in the same directory. All things inside each directory need *unique* names.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. Indeed they cannot have the same name, they can have .file appended to the end and then I'll just rename them.

I'm trying to create empty files that have the same name as the folders (with .file appended) in any given directory. These files should be created at the same level as the folders.

Comment: Quote your variables; if you don't know what I mean put your script into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) ...

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you could try:

```
find . -type d | while IFS= read -r d
do 
    ( cd "$d" && cd .. && touch "$(basename "$d").file" ) 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with awk, check this if its useful for you.
I am giving .file for file name

```
 realpath Fol*/* | awk '{print "touch "$1".file"}' | sh
```